# Laravel: Using mock instance in Customised Route::model binding

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, mockery

Route model binding in Laravel, helps bind an instance to the service container, to be used in a controller action. And the beautiful thing is that when I want to write tests, I can bind a mock instance to the application, which replaces what is bound to the container. - `App::instance($className, $mockInstance);`

I have made a request to the route (`Route::get("/{class_name}")`). I want to return an instance of the class, depending on what the value of the route parameter `class_name` is.

If the value is `two`, I want an instance of the `Two` class, likewise for the `One` class. Notice that both classes inherit from `AbstractClass`, so the returned instance is of type `AbstractClass`, (PHP7).

Problem: When I make visit the route, I get the correct instance. But when I want to use the mock instance, it overrides the mock instance and creates/returns the main instance. I need to use the mock instance so I can set expectations on it.

I've added some code, which I hope illustrates what I mean.

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
// abstract parent class
}

class One extends AbstractClass {
// single child class
}

class Two extends AbstractClass {
// another single child class
}

// I put this inside the `bind` method of the RouteServiceProvider
Route::bind("class_name", function (string $class_name) : AbstractClass {
 // I wish to return an instance to the route, based on the string that was passed - "one" or "two"
 $class = ucfirst($class_name);
 return new $class();
});

// test
public function testSomething () {
 $mockInstance = Mockery::mock(AbstractClass::class);
 App::instance(AbstractClass::class, $mockInstance);
 $response = $this->get("/one");
}
// controller method
public function action (AbstractClass $instance) {
 // I want to see/use the mock instance here, for testing
 // and the main instance otherwise.
}
```

I am using PHP7.0, with Laravel5.4 for development

Comment: I have tried using `$this->app->runningUnitTests()`, checking if I'm running tests, first before binding, which allows me to use the mock instance, but this also affects tests where I don't want to use the mock instance, but the main instance. In some test cases, I need to mock the instances because of some calls to some external APIs.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**
Well I guess you're confusing `Router bindings` vs `Container Bindings`. These two are completely separate in nature.

**Answer:**
Just update the router bindings when you're writing tests.

```
        $mock = Mockery::mock(AbstractClass::class);

        $this->app->get('router')->bind('class', function () use ($mock) {
             return $mock;
        });

        $response = $this->get("/test");
```

**Router Bindings:**
These bindings are only resolved when routing is involved, and it cannot be resolved when you're using `app()` instance.

**Container Bindings:**
Container bindings are separate and it doesn't know about the router bindings at all.