# Mocking model bindings fails when there are additional parameters

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am using Laravel's browserkit testing to test a route in my app.

The route is defined as:

web.php

```
Route::post("myroute/{mymodel}", "MyController@viewMyModel");
```

RouteServiceProvider

```
Route::model("mymodel", MyModel::class);
```

MyController

```
public function viewMyModel(Request $req, MyModel $myModel, $parameter) {
   //Does things
}
```

I need to now test the behaviour given a specific instance of MyModel

My test case is:

```
public function testDoesThingsWithoutFailing() {
    $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $this->app->instance(MyModel::class, $this->getMockBuilder(MyModel::class)->getMock());        
    $urlToVisit = url()->action("ReportsController@saveComponentAs", [
        "mymodel" => 123, "parameter" => "p"
    ]);
    $this->call("POST", $urlToVisit);
    $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
}
```

When I do this it fails due to the fact that "mymodel" is passed as the controller's 3 parameter because the 2nd one is injected from the container i.e. when I do `func_get_args` inside `viewMyModel` I get:

```
array:4 [
0 => Illuminate\Http\Request ...
1 => Mock_MyModel_6639c39c {...}
2 => "123"
3 => "p"
]
```

This is wrong (but expected) because parameter 2 is now injected rather than getting replaced by the route binding.

However when I try

```
$urlToVisit = url()->action("ReportsController@saveComponentAs", [
     "parameter" => "p"
]);
```

I get

> UrlGenerationException : Missing required parameters for [Route: ]

In an ideal world I would not need to use `$this->withoutMiddleware()` but I need to do this right now because it seems that if I don't the model is resolved normally rather than resolved via the container.

Am I doing something wrong here? Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: route its expecting a `mymodel` param which you did not provided, what if you change route param to `parameter`

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi here's the problem. I do provide it in the first instance of my test but then I get 123 passed as `$parameter` a 4th parameter with a value of `"p"` .. basically it gets shifted by one position (I've noted this when I shared the test case)

Comment: I am suspecting it might be a framework bug! However I will look into it after work! Looks very interesting bug.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I think I found what I was doing wrong here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354412/laravel-using-mock-instance-in-customised-routemodel-binding is the answer. I was disabling model binding by disabling middleware and using container binding but that is not correct. I need to keep and mock the model binding. I will answer as soon as I get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364768/487813 has led me to the correct solution.

The problem:

I disabled the middleware which disabled the route bindings, this was intentional because I thought I needed this. However this made the framework inject the model instead of replacing the parameter with the model. The parameter ended up being added to the request after all injected models.

The solution:

Keep using model binding but mock the binding result. Here's what works:

```
public function testDoesThingsWithoutFailing() {
    // Need the middleware to run
    $this->app->get('router')->bind(MyModel::class, function () { 
         return $this->getMockBuilder(MyModel::class)->getMock(); 
    }); 
    $urlToVisit = url()->action("ReportsController@saveComponentAs", [
        "mymodel" => 123, "parameter" => "p"
    ]);
    $this->call("POST", $urlToVisit);
    $this->assertResponseStatus(200); //Works as expected
}
```